# Linux: Get the grandchild's pid C++

Tags: c++, linux, fork, pid

I want to create a function where I pass a structure which will store the pid of the process that is spawned.

```
bool spawnHost(string ttyNumber, DeviceData &deviceData)    
{
   pid_t processID = fork();
   pid_t hostProcessID = -1;
   if (processID == -1)
   {
       printf("PID:%d-> Unable to fork a new process. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
       return false;
   }
   else if (!processID)
   {
       printf("PID:%d-> First child spawned. In Parent: %s", getpid(), processID);
       signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
       hostProcessID = fork();
       if (hostProcessID == -1)
       {
          printf("PID:%d-> Unable to fork a new process. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
          return false;
       }
       else if (!hostProcessID)
       {
          printf("PID:%d-> Starting %s at tty:%s", getpid(), hostAppPath.c_str(), ttyNumber.c_str());
          char *args[] = { (char *) hostAppPath.c_str(), (char *) ttyNumber.c_str(), NULL };
          execvp(hostAppPath.c_str(), args);
       }
       else
       {
          printf("PID:%d-> First child spawned. In child: %s", getpid(), hostProcessID);            
          sleep(5);
          exit(0);
       }
   }
   else
   {
      int childStatus;
      waitpid(processID, &childStatus, 0);
      if (WIFEXITED(childStatus))
         printf("PID:%d has exited with exit code %d\n", processID, WEXITSTATUS(childStatus));

      deviceData.setProcessID(hostProcessID);
      return true;
    }
}
```

The requirement here is that the host process (spawned in the second fork) shall not die, even if the parent process dies, and the pid of the host process shall be stored in a structure which was passed to the spawnHost() function. currently I am not able to get the pid. Is there something wrong with what I am dong?

I even tried the below approach:

```
bool spawnHost(string ttyNumber, DeviceData deviceData)
{   
    string hostAppPath = EXE_PATH;

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    pid_t processID = fork();

    if (processID == -1)
    {
        printf("PID:%d-> Unable to fork a new process. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
    else if (!processID)
    {
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        processID = fork();
        if (processID == -1)
        {
            printf("PID:%d-> Unable to fork a new process. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
            return false;
        }
        else if (!processID)
        {
            if (setsid() < 0)
            {
                printf("PID:%d-> Unable to set new session ID. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
                return false;
            }

            printf("PID:%d-> Starting %s at tty:%s", getpid(), hostAppPath.c_str(), ttyNumber.c_str());
            char *args[] = { (char *) hostAppPath.c_str(), (char *) ttyNumber.c_str(), NULL };
            execvp(hostAppPath.c_str(), args);
        }
        else
        {
            deviceData.setProcessID(processID);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        return true;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: On Linux you can trace the process hierarchy in /proc.

Comment: You need to call `pipe2(fds,O_CLOEXEC)`, and use that to pass information back until the process starts. I've written code that does this here: https://github.com/o11c/python-vterm/blob/master/vterm/c-sources/spawn.c

Comment: @JesperJuhl I tried to get the process tree for the second apporach, since the new process is started in a new session, hence it is nested to the init process and doesn't come under the main process tree

Comment: @o11c Thanks a lot, It worked. I was able to get the grandchild pid.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @o11c The answer that I implemented is:

```
bool spawnHost(string ttyNumber, DeviceData &deviceData)
{
    int pipefd[2];      
    string hostAppPath = HOST_PATH_PREFIX + HOST_NAME + BUILD_DIR_STRING + HOST_NAME;

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        printf("PID:%d-> IPC not possible as pipe failed");
        return false;
    }

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    pid_t processID = fork();

    if (processID == -1)
    {
        printf("PID:%d-> Unable to fork a new process. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    else if (!processID)
    {
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        processID = fork();
        if (processID == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!processID)
        {
            if (setsid() < 0)
            {
                printf("PID:%d-> Unable to set new session ID. Error: %s", getpid(), strerror(errno));
                return false;
            }
            char *args[] = { (char *) hostAppPath.c_str(), (char *) ttyNumber.c_str(), NULL };
            execvp(hostAppPath.c_str(), args);
        }
        else
        {
            /// Write the host pid to the pipe
            close(pipefd[0]);
            write(pipefd[1], &processID, sizeof(processID));
            close(pipefd[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[1]); /* Close unused write end */
        read(pipefd[0], &processID, sizeof(processID));
        close(pipefd[0]);
        wait(NULL);

        deviceData.setProcessID(processID);
        return true;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is much more understandable than what @o11c linked to. :)